# Javascript link click detector with alert window

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to set up a javascript click detector.
If the person clicks part 2 without clicking 'link1' or 'link2' an alert will pop up telling him to click one of the links.
If the person clicks a link he should be allowed to the thankyou page.
My problem is it doesn't ever let the user pass even if he clicked one of the links.

```
<a id="postos" href="http://link1.com">Link1</a><br>
<a id="postos" href="http://link2.com">Link2</a><br>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>   
<script>
    $("#postos").click(function () { 
        $("#linkos").attr('href', 'http://example.com');
    });
</script>

Part 2 Click <a id="linkos" href='javascript:window.alert("please click a link");'> Here </a>
```

Comment: @Diodeus Symantec agrees: http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/survey-scammers-moving-pinterest

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two elements with the same id.

Change it to a class:

```
<a class="postos" href="http://link1.com">Link1</a><br>
<a class="postos" href="http://link2.com">Link2</a><br>

$(".postos").click(function () { 
          $("#linkos").attr('href', 'http://example.com');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is invalid to have multiple times the same ID.

Add a class to your first links and select them using the class:

```
<a class="link" href="http://link1.com">Link1</a><br>
<a class="link" href="http://link2.com">Link2</a><br>

$(".link").click(function (e) { 
    $("#linkos").attr('href', 'http://example.com');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/x9GNe/)**

Comment: I guess those links are ads, so he doesn't want to "disable" them.

Comment: Indeed, they're likely to be visited. I'll change this.

Answer (score 0):

Id should be unique, so better user classes:

```
<a class="postos" href="http://link1.com">Link1</a><br>
<a class="postos" href="http://link2.com">Link2</a><br>
```

JS

```
$(".postos").click(function () { 
      $("#linkos").attr('href', 'http://example.com');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`id` must be unique, change from id to `class`:

**HTML:**

```
<a class="postos" href="http://link1.com">Link1</a><br>
<a class="postos" href="http://link2.com">Link2</a><br>

<a id="linkos" href='http://example.com'> Here </a>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.postos').click(function(){
        $(this).data('clicked', 'yes');
    })

$('#linkos').click(function(){
        if ($('.postos[data-clicked="yes"]').length == 0)
        {
            alert("please click a link");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<script>
  var next = function () {
    var confirmWindow = confirm("You want to go to a_website.");
    if (confirmWindow) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  };
</script>
<a href="your_url" onclick="return next();">Text here...</a>
```

Once the button is clicked (onclick attribute), it'll call a function.

Then the function will just ask the user if they want to go there.

The `true` or `false` will be returned depending on what button it clicks.

Then the `if` statement will just see if it's true or false.

Then the correct code will be ran.

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Little explanation to your code will be more helpful, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer